# FileStream BeginWrite or WriteAsync with IsAsync

Tags: c#, filestream

I am in a situation where i need to write to same file stream from different threads. The problem is that i cannot find any clear explanation whether i need to handle current stream position between writes ?

I open stream with FileOptions.Asynchronous option thus have an overlapped IO.

All write requests are coming in sequentially with buffers for next offset and from my test everything working fine and data is written correctly at file offsets.

But really can someone answer if there is no implications with this approach.

Comment: give code, get answers ... ;)

Comment: "All write requests are coming in sequentially" - sounds like you don't have overlapping request - please clarify. Obviously if requests are truly sequential (meaning next write does not start before previous one is complete) you don't need to manage position yourself...

Comment: No its not what i meant, i mean that all write requests coming in correct sequence.

Comment: using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\somefile.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[65536];
                for(int i = 0; i<4;i++)
                {
                    fs.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null, null);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a FileStream to another method through the parameter. For example:

```
public void FirstMethod(){
    FileStream filestream = new FileStream();
    //fill filestream
    SecondMethod(filestream);
}

public void SecondMethod(FileStream filestream)
    filestream.//do whatever you want with it
}
```

Or you can make a method return the filestream:

```
public FileStream FirstMethod() {
    FileStream filestream = new FileStream();
    //fill filestream
}

public void SecondMethod() {
    FileStream filestream = FirstMethod();
    //do what you want with it
}
```

If you could show us what you did, we can give you an answer that suits your situation.

Comment: well straight from the docs: "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." ([FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx)) - so I would not bet on this working without issues

Comment: Ah, now I understand, you want to catch the possibility that two methods are writing in the same file? Then i don't have the answer for you, sorry.

Comment: What I did in my project is using MemoryStream and passing it in between my classes until I was finished with it. 
Maybe theres a way to check wether a filestream is currently used? Like, if(filestream.inUse == true) {
//wait
} else {
//go ahead
}